# Consumir Api de Microsoft (Graph Explorer) para obtener datos de mi perfil en Vb.net o C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, vb.net

tento la siguiente consulta, deseo consumir un metodo GET desde el graph explorer de microsoft para poder obtener mi informacion de perfil de microsoft
la peticion únicamente recibe un token de acceso.

al hacer la pureba en postman y poner el bearer Token, funciona de maravilla pero a la hora de hacerlo desde codigo me dice que no esta autorizado

```
Public Function GetPerfilMicrosoft() As Task(Of List(Of DispositivoModel))
    Try
        Dim url As String = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Accept = "application/json"
        request.Headers("Token") = "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"
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

en el codigo anterior expongo la funcion que hago para consumir una api con token, pero me sale error 401 no autorizado

me podrian ayudar por favor

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El header para el token debe tener esta estrucutra:

```
request.Headers("Authorization") = "Bearer {token}"
```

Es decir el nombre del header es `Authorization` y en el token debes escribir "Bearer", luego un "espacio" y por último el token en cuestión

Ejemplo:

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim url As String = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Accept = "application/json"
    request.Credentials = New CredentialCache
    request.Headers("Authorization") = "Bearer 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"
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim streamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd())
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, funciona perfectamente

Comment: @IvanMauricioMarinLombo marca la respuesta como aceptada por favor. Así colaboras con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Gracias por el apoyo :D

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo que uses el cliente .Net adecuado, te ahorras muchas líneas de código:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
 var user = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"]
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

[Fuente](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)